# Custom toolbar navigation via menuitems to other activities

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, navigation, toolbar

i just started with Xamarin on programming the first app for the android platform.
Started with the custom toolbar, i ended up with no clue for navigation purposes on menuitems.

When my app starts, the custom toolbar is being display with my custom menuitems. So far, so good. When i click on a menuitem, the content needs to be switched to the other view.

I have created a class, lets call it "Settings" which is deprived from ListActivity.

```
public class UserSettingsActivity : ListActivity
{
            protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
                ListViewSetup();
            }

            private void ListViewSetup()
            {
                string[] actions = new string[] { "Add", "Modify", "Delete" };
                IListAdapter adapter = new ChangeSettingsAdapter(this, actions);
            }
}
```

As far as i understand, with ListActivity I don't have the need to create a seperate layout. My adapter does the rest for displaying the correct values as intended.

Now for the part which i have no clue about.

```
public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
{
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(UserSettingsActivity));
            StartActivity(intent);

            return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

When clicked on the menuitem, the values are being loaded, but no toolbar. I have no clickable "back-button".

What are my options to implement such features?

Do you need additional information to my case?

Comment: what do you mean with typeof(UserSettingsActivity), just starting the activity ?

Comment: Yes, when i am starting the activity, the view is getting changed and my listview is getting filled from my UserSettingsActivity. i edited my initial post.

Comment: sorry for being late, okay, one last question are you need the settings xml to be an activity or I might explain to you the fragment that's recommended from Google for drawer items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, you've a menu list on your action bar and you want to select the item to navigation to different pages. Then you need to set your `Toolbar` in each of your `Activity`, in order to make the `Toolbar` applied on every activities.

Or another common way to solve this issue is that you can use a `Fragment` or `FrameLayout` in your `MainActivity` and navigate your pages in this `Fragment`/ `FrameLayout`. For example:

Main layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/myframe"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Code behind:

```
public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
{
    Toast.MakeText(this, "Action selected: " + item.TitleFormatted,
        ToastLength.Short).Show();

    //if (item.TitleFormatted.ToString() == "Edit")
    //    StartActivity(typeof(Edit_Activity));
    //else if (item.TitleFormatted.ToString() == "Save")
    //    StartActivity(typeof(Save_Activity));
    if (item.TitleFormatted.ToString() == "Edit")
    {
        var newFragment = new Edit_Fragment();
        var ft = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        ft.Replace(Resource.Id.myframe, newFragment);
        ft.Commit();
    }
    else if (item.TitleFormatted.ToString() == "Save")
    {
        var newFragment = new Save_Fragment();
        var ft = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        ft.Replace(Resource.Id.myframe, newFragment);
        ft.Commit();
    }

    return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

By doing this, you will need to modify your rest activities to fragments, for example:

```
public class Edit_Fragment : Fragment
{
    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your fragment here
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
        return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.edit, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought about fragments as well, but haven't touched it yet. I will take a look. Meanwhile I have already found a solution: add the toolbar to every activity and use the homebackbutton. That's what you have written at the beginning.